# How to add a space to an existing string in Oracle character functions without using regular expressions

Tags: sql, oracle

I have a field as name in a table with names inserted without spaces. Eg: "MarkJones".

Now I want to create a space between the first and lastname of a person within the same column to be displayed as "Mark Jones" using Oracle functions.

I have tried this query

```
SELECT instr('MarkJones', '%||Upper(*)||%') AS substr1,
       SUBSTR('MarkJones', instr('MarkJones', '%lower(*)upper(*)%')) AS substr2,
       substr1||' '||substr2
FROM dual
;
```

However, this query is not working. I want to try it using oracle functions including `translate`, `substr` and `instr`, but no regular expressions.

Comment: Add some other persons, e.g. JamesMcConnell, and SaraO'Neil.

Comment: If nothing is like @jarlh said (this will definitely cause bugs) you could just replace every uppercase letter with a whitespace and the uppercase letter again as `trim(regexp_replace('MarkJones', '([A-Z])', ' \1'))`

Comment: Hi, thanks for your response. However, I need to do it without using regexp. I need to apply Oracle Character functions such as substr, instr and translate functions.

Comment: I have tried the above query, where my logic is to encounter the next first uppercase character in the string which marks the beginning of the Last-name/Surname, and hence putting a space just before that, however, the query is missing some logic and hence not working, hence I am seeking help over it.

Comment: @Sparkle_Doable - your current query gets ORA-00904 because you're trying to reference the substr1/2 column aliases in the same level of query. But you can't use wildcards (`%`) or patterns in `instr`; you are looking for the literal string `'%||Upper(*)||%'` which is not in `MarkJones`. Why don't you want to use regular expressions, which do allow patterns?

Answer (score 2):

This approach works for the simple example given, but fails if the name has more than 2 uppercase letters in it.  If this is coursework as expected, maybe the requirements are not too difficult for the names to parse as we all know that is fraught with heartache and you can never account for 100% of names from all nationalities.

Anyway my approach was to move through the string looking for uppercase letters and if found replace them with a space followed by the letter.  I used the ASCII function to test their ascii value to see if they were an uppercase character.  The CONNECT BY construct (needed to loop through each character of the string) returns each character in its own row so LISTAGG() was employed to reassemble back into a string and ltrim to remove the leading space.

I suspect if this is coursework it may be using some features you should not be using yet.  At least you should get out of this the importance of receiving and/or giving complete specifications!

```
SQL> with tbl(name) as (
     select 'MarkJones' from dual
   )
   select ltrim(listagg(case
          when ascii(substr(name, level, 1)) >= 65 AND
               ascii(substr(name, level, 1)) <= 90 THEN
            ' ' || substr(name, level, 1)
          else substr(name, level, 1)
          end, '')
          within group (order by level)) fixed
   from tbl
   connect by level <= length(name);

FIXED
------------------------------------
Mark Jones
```

When you are ready, here's the regexp_replace version anyway :-)
Find and "remember" the 2nd occurrence of an uppercase character then replace it with a space and the "remembered" uppercase character.

```
SQL> with tbl(name) as (
     select 'MarkJones' from dual
   )
   select regexp_replace(name, '([A-Z])', ' \1', 1, 2) fixed
   from tbl;

FIXED
----------
Mark Jones
```

Answer (score 1):

Not sure we should go against @Alex Poole advice, but it looks like an homework assignment.

So my idea is to point the second Upper Case. Its doable if you create a set of the upper cases, on which you valuate the position in input string `iStr`. Then if you're allowed to use `length`, you can use this position to build `firstName` too:

```
SELECT  substr(iStr, 1, length(iStr)-length(substr(iStr, instr(iStr, u)))) firstName
      , substr(iStr, instr(iStr, u))                                       lastName
      , substr(iStr, 1, length(iStr)-length(substr(iStr, instr(iStr, u)))) ||' '|| 
        substr(iStr, instr(iStr, u))                                       BINGO
FROM (           select 'MarkJones' iStr from dual
       union all select 'SomeOtherNames' from dual -- 2 u-cases gives 2 different results
       union all select 'SomeOtherOols'  from dual -- only one result
       union all select 'AndJim'         from dual
       union all select 'JohnLenon'      from dual
       union all select 'LemingWay'      from dual
     ),
     (           select 'A' U from dual
       union all select 'B'   from dual
       union all select 'C'   from dual
       union all select 'D'   from dual
       union all select 'E'   from dual
       union all select 'F'   from dual
       union all select 'G'   from dual
       union all select 'H'   from dual
       union all select 'I'   from dual
       union all select 'J'   from dual
       union all select 'K'   from dual
       union all select 'L'   from dual
       union all select 'M'   from dual
       union all select 'N'   from dual
       union all select 'O'   from dual
       union all select 'P'   from dual
       union all select 'Q'   from dual
       union all select 'R'   from dual
       union all select 'S'   from dual
       union all select 'T'   from dual
       union all select 'U'   from dual
       union all select 'V'   from dual
       union all select 'W'   from dual
       union all select 'X'   from dual
       union all select 'Y'   from dual
       union all select 'Z'   from dual
) upper_cases
where instr(iStr, U) > 1
;
```

Comment: My advice is usually worth exactly what you pay for it *8-) Homework seems like a likely reason to ban regex, but would be nice if the OP clarified the restrictions. Anyway, this gets two results for the second value, was that intentional?

Comment: That's right... It's the special case where an input string has more than 2 upper case letter. I'm not sure if OP wants to handle this case. And it gets more tricky if its twice the same, because it shows up once only...